# Communication between browsers with different scopes? angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use Drag and Drop HTML5 API to do interaction between browsers, but I'm also incorporating Angularjs with it as well. However, I came up to a conclusion that I don't think the way $scope works in Angularjs would allow me to move data from one browser window to another one. Is there a way to make this API works across browsers with Angularjs?

```
An example with angularjs:
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VIEz9iR8uMk9zlL24r1Y?p=preview

Comment: So I got it working with the plain javascript, but when using angularjs, that doesn't work well between windows

Comment: Please share some code